# How do you access parent and children relationships through the ORM with a conditional on the parent where record child exist?

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-models

I am trying to create a query through the Django ORM which is a straight join. I am trying to extract only records from parent table that have an entry in the child table, In addition, I would like to add a conditional on the parent table.

Here are the sample model:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

The SQL would look as follows:

```
Select * from Reporter 
JOIN Article ON Article.reporter_id = Reporter.id 
where Reporter.last_name="Jones"
```

How do I construct the query above using the Django ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do an inner join and return reporters:

```
Reporter.objects.filter(last_name='Jones', article__isnull=False)
```

(it will also add a harmless `article.id IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE`)

Comment: Thank you Pavel I really appreciate it. Have a reputation of 5 at the moment so I cannot unfortunately upvote this answer. Thanks