# select all records from the parent table assuming something is present in the child

Tags: python, django

I'm tying to traverse up a one-to-many relationship to efficiently select all records from the parent table assuming something is present in the child table.

from models.py

```
class Meter(models.Model):
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.IntegerField()

class Deal(models.Model):
    dealinfo = models.IntegerField()
```

in English, select all of the deals that have meters from company #2

in SQL:

```
select * from Deal
where Deal.id in
(
select distinct Deal_id
from Meter
where Meter.company = 2
);
```

I don't know how to do this without two queries. I can't even think of a good way to  google for a solution.

I tried this: 
    result = Deal.objects.filter(meter__company=2)
that I found here:
[How do you access parent and children relationships through the ORM with a conditional on the parent where record child exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982199/how-do-you-access-parent-and-children-relationships-through-the-orm-with-a-condi) but it's an inner join and doesn't implement the  "unique" phrase, so I get multiple records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be solved using [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

```
 result = Deal.objects.filter(meter__company=2).distinct()
```

Comment: thanks!  amazingly concise and obvious.  I appreciate your help.